# Trouble using regex in DocumentFilter for JTextField

Tags: java, regex, swing, jtextfield, documentfilter

I am using a `DocumentFilter` on a `JTextField` which is used to enter in the amount of time an employee has worked. the filter is to ensure that the limit of input is only 4 characters long and to only allow numbers. A decimal may or may not be used but should only be allowed to be entered once, once a decimal is entered, there should only allow for one more number. Meaning 9.5 or 10.5 should be accepted and 8.45 is not.

So far I am able to get about half of the total desired functionality. No more than 4 characters can be entered and only digits are allowed. The latter is accomplished using the `replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "")` method.

I've spent a lot of time watching tutorials, reading documentation and related questions such as [this](http://forums.devshed.com/java-help-9/regex-allow-decimal-395656.html), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2), and especially [this,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570820/regex-allow-digits-and-a-single-dot) but can't seem to get a regex to perform fully. One thing in particular than I can't figure out is why exactly a regex of `[^0-9]` will successfully only allow digits, but `^\\d` wont unless enclosed as a character class such as `[\\d]`

My filter code is below:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class TimeWorkedFilter extends DocumentFilter {

    private int maxCharacters;    

    public TimeWorkedFilter(int maxChars) {
        maxCharacters = maxChars;
    }
//"[^0-9.]
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs, String str, AttributeSet a)
            throws BadLocationException {

        if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length()) <= maxCharacters)
            super.insertString(fb, offs, str.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", ""), a);
        else
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }

    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length, String str, AttributeSet a)
            throws BadLocationException {

        if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length()
                - length) <= maxCharacters)
            super.replace(fb, offs, length, str.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", ""), a);
        else
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }
}
```

Comment: number filter is quite often aksed here

Comment: To answer your last question: `^` has a special meaning inside a character class (`[]`) definition. Otherwise, it simply means "start of string/line".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I can't figure out is why exactly a regex of [^0-9] will successfully only allow digits"

The `str` passed to your overridden methods (in terms of typing) is only a single character, as the filter methods are called every time you type in a character. The regex `[^0-9]` means not numbers. So when you do `str.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "")`, you are giving the filter permission to insert the character to the text field, as as long as it is a number, other wise it will add an empty character/string, giving the effect of the user not being able to enter a letter.

That being said, as for the real question

> " the filter is to ensure that the limit of input is only 4 characters long and to only allow numbers. A decimal may or may not be used but should only be allowed to be entered once, once a decimal is entered, there should only allow for one more number. Meaning 9.5 or 10.5 should be accepted and 8.45 is not."

As mentioned above, the `str` passed to the method is a single character, so if you try to pass a complete regex to the `str.replaceAll()` to match say `8.9`, it won't work. The regex in the `replaceAll()` is meant to just check the single character (in this case).

What you can do instead it get the text from the document, concatenate the `str` to the document and see if the total text `matches()` a complete regex. Something like

```
public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length, String str, AttributeSet a)
        throws BadLocationException {

    String text = fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength());
    text += str;
    if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length()
            - length) <= maxCharacters && text.matches("^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]{0,1}$")) {
        super.replace(fb, offs, length, str, a);
    } else {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }
}
```

Not sure if that's the exact regex your looking for. Regex is not my forte. I got the regex from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21704768/2587435)

Comment: excellent answer. I didn't realize I was failing before because the filter was taking it per character. I guess I should have but I'm still pretty new to Java and basically am just teaching myself.