# Prevent char entering on java swing JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener

I'm using java swing and trying to enter Numbers only into a JTextField.

when typing a char I want to show an Invalid message, **and prevent from typing** the char into the JTextField.

```
        idText.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            try
            {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(idText.getText()+e.getKeyChar());
                validText.setText("");
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e1) {
                e.consume();
                validText.setText("Numbers Only!");
            }
        }
    });
```

for some reason, e.consume() doesnt work as I expected, and i can type chars.

Comment: Does replacing the `keyPressed` method with `keyTyped` work?

Answer (score 6):

Generally, adding a custom `KeyListener` to prevent characters in a `JTextField` is not recommended. It would be better for users (and easier for you as programmer) to use a component that it has been created for only-numbers input.

1. [JSpinner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) is one of them.
2. [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) is another one.

If you insist of doing it your self though, it would be better to achieve it with a [DocumentFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844559/jtextfield-using-document-filter-to-filter-integers-and-periods) and not with a `KeyListener`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477354/how-to-allow-introducing-only-digits-in-jtextfield) is another example as well.

In addition to these examples, here is my solution:

```
public class DocumentFilterExample extends JFrame {
    public DocumentFilterExample() {
        super("example");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JTextField field = new JTextField(15);
        AbstractDocument document = (AbstractDocument) field.getDocument();
        document.setDocumentFilter(new OnlyDigitsDocumentFilter());
        add(field);

        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new DocumentFilterExample().setVisible(true));
    }

    private static class OnlyDigitsDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {
        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
            text = keepOnlyDigits(text);
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
        }

        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            string = keepOnlyDigits(string);
            super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }

        private String keepOnlyDigits(String text) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            text.chars().filter(Character::isDigit).forEach(sb::append);
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1000 upvotes for recommending NOT to use a KeyListener

Comment: I used your answer, but I had to add the following code
`.mapToObj(Character::toChars)`
 to your streaming code in the `keepOnlyDigits` method. I provided an additional answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the `DocumentFilterExample` answer that is already here, but I am submitting an 'answer' to add some additional code that I had to use to get it to work properly.

I had to modify the `keepOnlyDigits` method to map the `int` character values to the `char` character values.

```
        private String keepOnlyDigits(String text) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            text.chars().filter(Character::isDigit)
                    .peek(charInt -> System.out.println("before: " + charInt))
                    .mapToObj(Character::toChars) // Added this line
                    .peek(toChar -> System.out.println("after: " + toChar[0]))
                    .forEach(sb::append);
            return sb.toString();
        }
```

Here is the output with that change, running the `DocumentFilterExample`'s `main` method:
[image]

I added the `peek` to show the value that was printed out before my change, and after my change.

My change was the addition of the `.mapToObj(Character::toChars)` to the Stream  code.