# Why the following regular expression is not allowing numbers?

Tags: java, regex, swing, jtextfield, documentfilter

Well, this might sound as if it is a duplicate question but it is not. I have asked this question in connection with [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776908/filtering-a-jtextfield-for-strings-space-and-a-dot-using-a-documentfilter). I have rewritten my `DocumentFilter` to use regular expressions. In validating a person's name I want only the following characters `[a-zA-Z]`,`'`,`\S` and `.`.

I have written my regular expression with the hope that it will solve this. It is working the way I want it **but the fact that it is not allowing numbers when I have not yet set it to do so is puzzling me.**

**Question:** Why is `regex` not allowing numbers?

This is the regular expression `[\\_\\(\\)@!\"#%&*+,-:;<>=?\\[\\]\\^\\~\\{\\}\\|]` and what it should not allow to be entered is commented in the code below:

My DocumentFilter is as follows:

```
public class NameValidator extends DocumentFilter{
@Override
public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int off
                    , String str, AttributeSet attr) 
                            throws BadLocationException 
{
    // remove 0-9 !"#$%&()*+,-/:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
    fb.insertString(off, str.replaceAll("^[\\_\\(\\)@!\"#%&*+,-:;<>=?\\[\\]\\^\\~\\{\\}\\|]", ""), attr);
} 
@Override
public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int off
        , int len, String str, AttributeSet attr) 
                        throws BadLocationException 
{
    // remove 0-9 !"#$%&()*+,-/:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
    fb.replace(off, len, str.replaceAll("^[\\_\\(\\)@!\"#%&*+,-:;<>=?\\[\\]\\^\\~\\{\\}\\|]", ""), attr);
   }
}
```

Here is my test class:

```
public class NameTest {

private JFrame frame;

public NameTest() throws ParseException {
    frame = new JFrame();
    initGui();
}

private void initGui() throws ParseException {

    frame.setSize(100, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 5));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTextField name = new JTextField(10);
    ((AbstractDocument)name.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new NameValidator());
    frame.add(name);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                NameTest nt = new NameTest();
            } catch (ParseException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
     });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just add the `0-9` numbers to the regex: `[0-9\\_\\(\\)@!\"#%&*+,-:;<>=?\\[\\]\\^\\~\\{\\}\\|]`

Comment: @stribizhev Well, I mean the regex is NOT allowing numbers  **BEROFE I have set it to do so**, the way you have done above. I was about to put it the way you have done, BUT before that it is already not allowing numbers! I hope I have explained better.

Comment: @Giovanrich: I overlooked `,-:`, it really already captures numbers that you remove.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is this part of your regex:

```
,-:
```

Which matches any character in the range of `,` (ASCII 44) to `:` (ASCII 58), which includes all the numbers (ASCII 48-57 inclusive).

If you escape the `-` it should work fine and not match numbers:

```
[\\_\\(\\)@!\"#%&*+,\\-:;<>=?\\[\\]\\^\\~\\{\\}\\|]
```

Comment: or put it in the beginning or ending.

Comment: The `[,-:]` actually matches `, - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 :`

Comment: Very well, this is what I was looking for! Thanks - all I had to do is to escape it. I will accept your answer soon.