# How in Java I can create a field that can accept only digits and once dot?

Tags: java, regex, swing, jtextfield, documentfilter

I look all over the net and all the things I tried didn't work....

I found that I can use some JTextFormatterField but it didn't work.

Then I found that I can use DocumentFilter with regex and that what I did:

```
JTextField jFormattedTextFieldMoneyToConvert = new JTextField();
    ((AbstractDocument) jFormattedTextFieldMoneyToConvert.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter(){
        Pattern regEx = Pattern.compile("^\\d+\\.?\\d*$");

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
            Matcher matcher = regEx.matcher(text);
            if (!matcher.matches()) {
                return;
            }
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
        }
    });
```

but it doesn't work...It accepts only digits. I want it to accept also dots. And I also need it to not to start with a dot and not to end with a dot.

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `but it doesn't work...` please define ...

Comment: sorry, I edited my question

Comment: `I also need it to not to start with a dot and not to end with a dot.` - the expression for that would be `^\d+(\.\d+)?$`, i.e. at least one digit optionally followed by a dot and at least one more digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a [similar problem a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21704583/2587435). The problem wasn't with the regex, but my misunderstanding of how the filter works. My assumption, like yours was that the `String text` passed to the `replace` method, is the entire string, when it's really only the character being typed. Similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23502927/2587435).

While all of [@Bohemian's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30168153/2587435) regex kung-fu might be what your looking for in terms of a matching regex (I don't know, it's not my forte), the problem (with the assumption) can be fixed by obtaining the entire document text, then try and match *that*, i.e.

```
String completeText = fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength());
```

> "And I also need it to not to start with a dot and not to end with a dot"

Think about this logically for a second. The filter is called for each character input. But you don't want to end with `.` but you want to allow `.` somewhere in the middle. Not allowing `.` at the end negate the possibility of a `.` at all as you would need to type a `.` at the end before the next number

You could probably just write a focus listener to add a 0 or remove the `.` when the field loses focus, if the user leaves a hanging `.`

---

**UPDATE: full example**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class FilterDemo {

    public FilterDemo() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.add(createFilteredField());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private JTextField createFilteredField() {
        JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
        AbstractDocument document = (AbstractDocument) field.getDocument();
        final int maxCharacters = 10;
        document.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
            @Override
            public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length,
                    String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {

                String text = fb.getDocument().getText(0,
                        fb.getDocument().getLength());
                text += str;
                if (text.matches("^\\d+\\.?\\d*$")) {   //  "^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]{0,}$"
                    super.replace(fb, offs, length, str, a);
                } else {
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs, String str,
                    AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {

                String text = fb.getDocument().getText(0,
                        fb.getDocument().getLength());
                text += str;
                if (text.matches("^\\d+\\.?\\d*$")) {
                    super.insertString(fb, offs, str, a);
                } else {
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                }
            }
        });
        return field;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FilterDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you right. how can I do it with the dot at the end?

Comment: Have you tried it wit the regex you're currently using? Looks like it should work, as log as you make the fix I mentioned

Comment: yes, fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength()); is empty...
fb.getDocument().getLength() returns 0

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. See update will full program

Comment: Yeah so I forgot the fact that the new string/character is not actually inserted into the document yet. That's why the need to concatenate before matching :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is probably the simplest code that works:

```
if (text.matches("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"))
```

If there's a dot, it must be followed by some digits. If you want to allow a dot then *no* digits too, change the `+` to `*`:

```
if (text.matches("\\d+(\\.\\d*)?"))
```

Note that with `String#matches()`, the leading/trailing `^`/`$` are not necessary as they are *implied*, because the *entire* string must be matched for `matches()` to return `true`.

Allowing no leading digits too becomes trickier, because the regex `(\d+)?(\.\d*)` matches the blank string, so you need an alternation:

```
if (text.matches("\\d+(\\.\\d*)?|\\.\\d+"))
```

or a negative look ahead:

```
if (text.matches("(?!$)\\d*(\\.\\d*)?"))
```

The little look head asserts that the next position after the start is not the end (ie input is not blank).